# How to fix factory error when add PVA as a skill to Bot

Tags: azure, botframework, power-virtual-agents

I'm developing a bot with Power Virtual Agents which is used by trough LINE messenger.

PVA <--> Azure Bot Service <--> LINE

I tried the following instruction, but the bot says "ReservationChat3.dialog error: Type Microsoft.OrchestratorRecognizer not registered in factory."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-virtual-agents/advanced-use-pva-as-a-skill

And the log is...

- "ReservationChat3" is my bot name

```
fail: Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Runtime.CoreBotAdapter[0]
      [OnTurnError] unhandled error : ReservationChat3.dialog error: Type Microsoft.OrchestratorRecognizer not registered in factory.

System.InvalidOperationException: ReservationChat3.dialog error: Type Microsoft.OrchestratorRecognizer not registered in factory.

 ---> System.ArgumentException: Type Microsoft.OrchestratorRecognizer not registered in factory.
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Declarative.Resources.ResourceExplorer.BuildType[T](String kind, JToken obj, JsonSerializer serializer)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Declarative.Converters.InterfaceConverter`1.BuildOrGetType(String kind, JToken tokenToBuild, JsonSerializer serializer, Boolean passTwo, String cacheKey)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Declarative.Converters.InterfaceConverter`1.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateDictionary(IDictionary dictionary, JsonReader reader, JsonDictionaryContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ResolvePropertyAndCreatorValues(JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObjectUsingCreatorWithParameters(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, ObjectConstructor`1 creator, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract objectContract, JsonProperty containerMember, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id, Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultCreator)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerProxy.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject(Type objectType, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Declarative.Loaders.DefaultLoader.Load(JToken obj, JsonSerializer serializer, Type type)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Declarative.Resources.ResourceExplorer.BuildType[T](String kind, JToken obj, JsonSerializer serializer)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Declarative.Converters.InterfaceConverter`1.BuildOrGetType(String kind, JToken tokenToBuild, JsonSerializer serializer, Boolean passTwo, String cacheKey)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Declarative.Converters.InterfaceConverter`1.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IList list, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ResolvePropertyAndCreatorValues(JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObjectUsingCreatorWithParameters(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, ObjectConstructor`1 creator, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract objectContract, JsonProperty containerMember, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id, Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultCreator)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerProxy.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject(Type objectType, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Declarative.Loaders.DefaultLoader.Load(JToken obj, JsonSerializer serializer, Type type)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Declarative.Resources.ResourceExplorer.BuildType[T](String kind, JToken obj, JsonSerializer serializer)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Declarative.Converters.InterfaceConverter`1.BuildOrGetType(String kind, JToken tokenToBuild, JsonSerializer serializer, Boolean passTwo, String cacheKey)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Declarative.Converters.InterfaceConverter`1.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ResolvePropertyAndCreatorValues(JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObjectUsingCreatorWithParameters(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, ObjectConstructor`1 creator, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract objectContract, JsonProperty containerMember, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id, Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultCreator)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject(Type objectType, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject[T](JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Declarative.Resources.ResourceExplorer.Load[T](JToken token, SourceContext sourceContext)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Declarative.Resources.ResourceExplorer.LoadTypeAsync[T](Resource resource, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Declarative.Resources.ResourceExplorer.LoadTypeAsync[T](Resource resource, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.AdaptiveDialogBot.CreateDialogAsync()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.AdaptiveDialogBot.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.SetSpeakMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.MiddlewareSet.ReceiveActivityWithStatusAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotAdapter.RunPipelineAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I've tried to find any method to add Microsoft.OrchestratorRecognizer to my factory in my Bot Framework Composer.
But I couldn't find it...

How can I add Microsoft.OrchestratorRecognizer to my factory?